# Hiding tick marks and tick labels of minimum and maximum limits of axes for base R plots

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

Suppose I make a barplot and a scatterplot using the following lines of code:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
xlabs <- c("A", "B", "C")
y <- c(4, 5, 6)

barplot(x,
        xlab = "X",
        names.arg = xlabs,
        ylim = c(0, 3),
        ylab = "Y")

plot(x, y,
        xlim = c(1, 3),
        xlab = "X",
        ylim = c(4, 6),
        ylab = "Y")
```

How can the axes tick marks and tick labels *for the minimum and maximum limits only* be hidden? Here is what I intend to accomplish:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options. First, you generally want to drop the default axis labels using `xaxt='n'` or `yaxt='n'`. Next, you could manually specify the locations of the tick marks in `axis()` or use the `pretty()` function with dropping the first and last values (used `head` and `tail` in example) to get some nice tick mark locations. It might require some manual fine tuning.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
xlabs <- c("A", "B", "C")
y <- c(4, 5, 6)

barplot(x,
        xlab = "X",
        names.arg = xlabs,
        ylim = c(0, 3),
        ylab = "Y",
        yaxt='n' # drops the y axis and tick marks
        )
# draw a vertical line that will cover the whole vertical axis, if desired
abline(v=par('usr')[1],lwd=2)
# pretty will give nice tickmark locations, and head and tail drop first and last
# add the 0 to x vector because barplot starts at 0
axis(side=2,tail(pretty(c(0,x)),-1)) 

plot(x, y,
     xlim = c(1, 3),
     xlab = "X",
     ylim = c(4, 6),
     ylab = "Y",
     xaxt='n', # no default x axis with ticks
     yaxt='n' # no default y axis with ticks
     )
# add tickmark and axis locations manually for each axis
# using the pretty function for where the tick marks normally would be, then head and tail to drop first and last
axis(side=1,tail(head(pretty(c(x)),-1),-1)) 
axis(side=2,tail(head(pretty(c(y)),-1),-1))
```

[image: scatterplot]

[image: barplot]

Comment: Thank you very much.  The tail(pretty(c(minimum limit, maximum limit)), -1) and the tail(head(pretty(c(minimum limit, maximum limit)), -1), -1) worked perfectly. However, I noticed that suppressing axes limits also changes the axes intervals, so I remedied the issue using at = seq(penultimate to minimum, penultimate to maximum, by = n).

Comment: Also, I noticed that abline(h = par('usr')[n], lwd = n) and abline(v = par('usr')[n], lwd = n)  is kind of a hit-and-miss solution to covering sections of the axes truncated by the process, but I observed that inserting axis(side = n, pos = minimum limit (for sides 1 or 2) or maximum limit (for sides 3 or 4), at = c(minimum limit:maximum limit) or at = seq(minimum limit, maximum limit, by = n), tck = 0, labels = FALSE) after the lines containing the head and/or tail functions is more reliable.